# VSCode .NET SDK is using the version from VisualStudio instead of the version I want it to use

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, sdk

I have installed .NET SDK 7.0 to run an application in my **vscode**.
I have **visual studio** installed with .NET 8.0 to run a different application.

**VSCode** has adopted the version I am using for **Visual Studio** and is not allowing my code to run anymore for local dev environment.
 `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\NuGet.targets(156,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/. [C:\GitHub\sitecore-style-guide\sitecore-style-guide.sln] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\NuGet.targets(156,5): error :   The content at 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/' is not a valid JSON object. [C:\GitHub\sitecore-style-guide\sitecore-style-guide.sln] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\NuGet.targets(156,5): error :   Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0. [C:\GitHub\sitecore-style-guide\sitecore-style-guide.sln] dotnet watch ⏳ Waiting for a file to change before restarting dotnet...`

Here is the error that is being thrown when I run my dotnet watch command to perform hot reloads of my **VSCode** project.

I can solve the issue by uninstalling the 8.0 version of my **visual studio** but that is not a long term solution.

I have seen there is a path to set the SDK in **VSCode** but it is not working or I am doing something incorrect.